# How to parse comma-separated integers from user input

Tags: python, io

I'd like to accept a user input consisting of several comma-separated integers and put them in a list. The values are separated by commas. Let's say I'm giving `100,97,84` as input, the desired output would be `[100, 97, 84]`. I'm trying the following code:

```
int(input("Please enter the numbers: "))
```

but it gives me:

```
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '100,97,84'
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

`input` will always return a string, even if it is a digit

If you want a number you write `int(input"Enter number :))`

I don't know what's the relation between your output and input, however you are looking to enter a `list` as an `input`. You can do that by

```
s = (input("Enter the numbers :"))
numbers = list(map(int, s.split()))
```

This will return a list in `numbers`. You enter the numbers with a `space` in between not a `comma`

E.g

```
Enter the numbers :100 97 84
Ouput>>>[100, 97, 84]
```

If you want them without the brackets and separated by a comma, you can use
`print(*numbers, sep=',')`
will give

```
Enter the numbers :100 97 84
Output>>>100,97,84
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write number separated by a comma, first you have to split your input into a list of digit only strings and then map this list through int:

```
numbers = [int(s) for s in input("Please enter numbers separated by a comma:").split(',')]
```

Answer (score 0):

Because your phrase contains a comma, put it in a quotation mark to convert it to an integer with the following phrase :

```
s = (input("Enter the numbers :"))
result = ''.join([i for i in s if  i.isdigit()])
print(result)
```

example

```
Enter the numbers :12,34
```

output:

```
1234
```

The error problem will be solved

Comment: No, the OP wants to enter three distinct integers, not one big integer.

Comment: I think the numbers are entered in the form of 123,456, which is a combination of numbers and commas that are converted to numbers with the above code.